# Have no Internet connection over Crosscable

Tags: configuration, internet, connection, patch, failover

I bought a Crosscable and wanted to configure my Server, like it's said in the Wiki.

But when I connect, I don't get wireless Internet  and the Lan Adapter says I am connected, but I have no Internet and also can't access the server.

I need help please.

Comment: Do you mean a crossover/patch cable? Ethernet?

Comment: yes I mean this one :)

Answer (score 0):

[Ethernet crossover cables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_cable_%28ethernet%29) are only meant to be used to connect two computers. You can't use them to connect a computer with the internet.

Comment: No I connect to pcs and the one pc is also connected to the internet.

Comment: That's something you have to include in the question. Is the PC over which you want to connect your server, running Windows or Linux? How does that one connect to the internet?

Comment: The Computer i want to connect have Linux and Windows, the computer who is connected to the Internet runs Linux. He is connected over an Lan Patchcable. And my Laptop will be connected with a Crossover Lancable over another Lan Pci Card. I have a connection, but no internet.